# cant find finger print sensor driver for '10a5:a900' on my Honor leptop device

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader

this is my first community post!

i really like using linux, its been more than 2 years using it..im happy and ther's no going back to windows, or mac anytime soon.

I am having difficulty finding appropriate drivers for my fingerprint sensor **'10a5:a900'** i had googled it tried to figure it out myself, like all other issues in past but i cant seem to find any concrete by myself.

I'm asking you guys if you can help, this is only the thing i can't figure out from past 6 months.

when i `lsusb`

this results  :
`Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub` 
`Bus 003 Device 003: ID 3277:0045 ShineOptics HD Camera` 
`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10a5:a900 FPC FPC Sensor Controller L:0002 FW:22.26.2.29` 
`Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth` 
`Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub` 
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub` 
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub` 
`

from which i suspect my fingerprint sensor is : 
`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10a5:a900 FPC FPC Sensor Controller L:0002 FW:22.26.2.29`

obviously i cant set-up my fingerprint authentication as the finger print sensor is not detected properly...

```
fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger
```

Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

any help regarding ***'10a5:a900'*** will be helpful, i have read many articles but haven't found any articles regarding this specific sensor.

my leptop specs : honor magickbook pro x14 2023